# unable to understand the results of using aggregate function in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my DB called cities, with id, name , country_id, lat(latitude) and lng(longitude).
In my application I get the user's location, then try to find out which city is closest to the user's location so at first I did something like this:

```
select * , ( sqrt( pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2) ) ) as min_dis from cities
```

which returned results like this:

```
+----+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
| id | name             | country_id | lat           | lng           | min_dis              |
+----+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
|  1 | Cairo            |         61 | 30.0444196000 | 31.2357116000 |   1.7642055948326205 |
|  2 | Alexandria       |         61 | 31.2000924000 | 29.9187387000 | 0.012723270627083274 |
|  3 | Tanta            |         61 | 30.7865086000 | 31.0003757000 |   1.1707286078440424 |
|  7 | North Coast      |         61 | 28.0488161000 | 34.4371483000 |    5.521208240105792 |
|  8 | Marsa Matruh     |         61 | 31.3543445000 | 27.2373159000 |    2.673858069059212 |
|  9 | Hurghada         |         61 | 27.2578957000 | 33.8116067000 |    5.552079415567052 |
| 10 | Ismailia         |         61 | 30.5964923000 | 32.2714587000 |   2.4415049795085366 |
| 11 | Ain ElSokhna     |         61 | 29.5927778000 | 32.3416667000 |    2.920079170546876 |
| 12 | El Mansoura      |         61 | 31.0409483000 | 31.3784704000 |    1.480587078948432 |
+----+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

as you can see in the results "Alexandria" city, with ID=2 is the closest to the user's location.

And when I try something like this:

```
select MIN( sqrt( pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2) ) ) as min_dis from cities;
```

I get this:

```
+----------------------+
| min_dis              |
+----------------------+
| 0.012723270627083274 |
+----------------------+
```

which makes sense to me... but when I try this:

```
select * , MIN( sqrt( pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2) ) ) as min_dis from cities;
```

I get this:

```
+----+-------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
| id | name  | country_id | lat           | lng           | min_dis              |
+----+-------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
|  1 | Cairo |         61 | 30.0444196000 | 31.2357116000 | 0.012723270627083274 |
+----+-------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

the min_dis returned is correct, but the city data is not!! I thought it should have returned the record of "Alexandria" but it didn't ..
Does anyone know why??

**EDIT:**
this query worked for me:

```
SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE ((sqrt(pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2)))= (SELECT MIN((sqrt(pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2)))) AS min_id FROM `cities` ))
```

and returned:

```
+----+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | name       | country_id | lat           | lng           |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  2 | Alexandria |         61 | 31.2000924000 | 29.9187387000 |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

All I just want is to understand why didn't this query work?

```
select * , MIN( sqrt( pow(lat - 31.205 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.907 , 2) ) ) as min_dis from cities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use aggregate functions, any non-aggregate fields have to be correctly specified with the `GROUP BY` statement, otherwise you'll end up with an unspecified result, which is usually the first or last record used in the aggregate collation.

`MIN(...)` does not mean return the minimum from the table, it means the minimum for the current group, which is specified by the leading fields and the `GROUP BY` statement.  If you want the minimum for the whole table, with the other records, you do need to either use an `ORDER BY` to get the lowest record, as **Joe G Joseph** did above, or do as you have done and tell it to match a subquery that gets the `MIN(...)` of the whole table via virtue of having no grouping fields.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select * , ( sqrt( pow(lat - 30.4990 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.4435 , 2) ) ) 
                                                    as min_dis 
from cities 
order by sqrt( pow(lat - 30.4990 , 2) + pow(lng - 29.4435 , 2) ) 
limit 1
```

You just have to do an order by in your first query to get the result

Comment: your solution seems valid.. but it is not what I need.
When you order a set, it takes O(N Log N) , but getting the minimum only takes O(N), so using order will cause bad performance from large datasets.